# TwoWay Binding в DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding

У меня в программе есть часть интерфейса используемая несколько раз. Я естественно захотел её поместить в DataTemplate и потом показывать её в нужном месте с помощью ContentPresenter:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flagPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>   // <-- Mode=TwoWay
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Flag}"/>
```

Но проблема в том, что TextBox работает в режиме TwoWay, который требует наличие Path или XPath и выкидывает сообщение об ошибке. Пробовал сделать так:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flagPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>   // <-- Mode=TwoWay
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Flag}"/>
```

Заработало, но только в одном направлении от Source к Target. Если же сделать так:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flagPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Flag}"/>   // <-- Mode=TwoWay
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"/>
```

то всё работает как надо (в обе стороны), но мне нужно избежать использование Path в DataTemplate, т.к. Path в разных частях интерфейса может быть разным! Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Сделать байндинг к строке в обе стороны без Path не получится, т.к. WPF не знает, где эту самую строку нужно обновлять. Ваш код с `ContentPresenter` выглядит длиннее, чем аналогичный код с `TextBox`. Что вы на самом деле хотите сделать?

Comment: Ну в DataTemplate на самом деле сложный кусок интерфейса, просто упростил чтоб не загромождать. Но смысл всё тот-же как из DataTemplate сделать TwoWay Binding?

Comment: Обертку для строки использовать. Еще, в теории, можно написать контрол, в который вы будете передавать, например, имя свойства и класс, в котором это свойство нужно менять.

Comment: Не понял какую именно обёртку и для какой строки. И там вообще то кнопка "ответить" ниже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так - создал класс производный от DependencyObject, сделал в нём DependencyProperty:

```
public class Binder : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Binding", typeof(int), typeof(Binder), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int Binding
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BindingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindingProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

и использовал его как посредника в привязке:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flagPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Binding, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<local:Binder x:Key="binder1" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Flag1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource binder1}}"/>
```

Так сохраняется возможность использовать один DataTemplate с TwoWay binding для разных привязок. Например ни чего не мешает сделать ещё один ContentPresenter привязанный к другому объекту Flag2:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource binder2}}"/>
```

Минус конечно, в том что приходится создавать объекты класса Binder, которые к тому же нельзя сделать шаблонами Binder, т.к. XAML шаблоны не понимает.

Интересно, что в данном конкретном случае можно решить проблему и по другому используя RelativeSource в привязке:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource flagPanel}" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Flag1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Но есть тут одна засада, cтоит добавить в шаблон обрамляющий ContentControl, например так:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flagPanel">
    <Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Path=Content}"/>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

как привязка перестает работать. Почему я не понял, но предполагаю, что связано это именно с логикой работы ContentPresenter.